# compile c++ code with and without fopenmp flag

Tags: c++, fortran, openmp

I have installed the C++ and Fortran compiler and tested the (C++) programs
(serial and parallel versions).

in Fortran when compiling a (parallelized) code without enabling the `-openmp` option should compile the code in (default) serial mode

but in C++ I get errors like 
undefined reference to `omp_get_thread_num`

but in Fortran when you compile code without the -fopenmp flag it ignores any code which start with `$!omp` like

```
$!omp id = omp_get_thread_num()
```

Is there any option like that in C++?

Comment: Minor point, but I think you mean `!$` for fortan and not `$!`?

Comment: @d_1999 Make sure you improve everything in the post if your edits still require a review.

Comment: @ali you can use cpp macros

Comment: C uses #pragma in the place where fortran uses !$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can protect your C/C++ code with the _OPENMP define. This way you can avoid introducing calls to the OpenMP runtime whenever your application is not linked against it.

For instance, you can have the following code

```
void foo (void)
{
#ifdef _OPENMP
   printf ("I have been compiled with OpenMP support\n");
#else
   printf ("I have been compiled without OpenMP support\n");
#endif
}
```